# Weibull Regression of Left Truncated Data in R

Tags: r, regression, weibull-distribution, truncation

I have a data set of tree diameters that do not include any measurements below a 7.5 due to the difficulty in identifying species when they are small. I want to run a Weibull regression that returns the parameters Shape & Scale that correspond to the forest stand rather than my truncated sample. For illustration purposes I have created a mock dataset in R with known parameters.

```
control <- rweibull(10000, shape = 1, scale = 10) 
           # 10000 Random Samples From A Weibull Dist 
           # W/ Shape =1 Scale =10
cutoff <- control[control > 7.5]  
    # Removing All Samples Less Than 7.5 to Mimic My Data
```

Using the function `fitdistr` from the package MASS for Maximum-likelihood fitting of univariate distributions yields undesirable parameters for the truncated data.

```
library(MASS)
fit_control <- fitdistr(control, "weibull")
fit_cutoff <- fitdistr(cutoff, "weibull")
```

[image: Histograms]

The regression worked well for the control data set, Shape ~ 1 and Scale ~ 10. However, things are obviously different with the truncated data set. I understand why but I am looking for a method to get similar values for the parameters from the truncated to describe the forest stand.

I attempted to create a truncated distribution of the Weibull for R to fit the data to by subtracting the cumulative distribution up to 7.5 from the density function.

```
Trunc_Weibull <- function(x, shape, scale, log = FALSE){
  dweibull(x, shape, scale, log)-pweibull(7.5, shape, scale, 
       lower=FALSE) 
}
fit_truncated <- fitdistr(cutoff, Trunc_Weibull, 
         start = list(shape=0.5, scale=0.5))
```

This yields closer results but still not the desired output. Shown below is the cutoff and control histograms with the results from the truncated regression of the cutoff dataset.

[image: Truncated]

The desired output would be: Shape ~ 1 and Scale ~ 10.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood for the dataset will be $\mathcal{L} \left( \alpha , \beta \right) = \left( F_{\alpha \beta} \left( 7.5 \right)\right)^{i} \prod_{j=i+1}^{n} f_{\alpha \beta}\left( x_{j} \right) $ where $i$ of your $n$ data points are left censored and $F$ is the cumulative distribution function and $f$ the probability density function.